# Protractor validate message in smoke test suite

Tags: protractor, message

I have a issue when i run a suite of smoke test which issue is not happens with mock tests.

Code:

```
    it('should save widget', function () {
    explorerObjectInstance.on.metricsSelector
        .when
        .searchMetricOnTab('application', 0);

    explorerObjectInstance.on.metricsSelector
        .when
        .selectMetric(0);

    explorerObjectInstance.on.filtersPanel.given
        .selectAggregation(0);

    explorerObjectInstance.on.widget.given
        .changeTitle('Widget');

    explorerObjectInstance.on.topToolbox.given
        .saveButtonClick();

    saveWidgetObjectInstance.given
        .saveButtonPopupClick();

    //Error here
    notificationObjectInstance.then
        .itShouldHaveSuccess('Widget Created Successfully');

    explorerObjectInstance.then
        .itShouldBeVisibleSaveAsBtt();

});
```

POM:

```
        itShouldHaveSuccess: function (expectedMessage) {
            expect(successNotification().isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
            expect(context().getText()).toEqual(expectedMessage);
            return this;
        }
```

Selectors:

```
function context () {
    return element(by.tagName('notifications'));
}

function successNotification () {
    return element(by.css('.alert-success'));
}
```

Problem:
The problem is that the protractor can not validate the message, although the element is present on DOM.

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with your context() selector. Is there actually a component w/ the tagName 'notifications'? If you are trying to target based on the class or ID, the proper selector would be:

```
function context() {
     return element(by.css('.notifications'));
}
```

or

```
function context() {
     return element(by.css('#notifications'));
}
```